# combine array of objects from two files with jq under specific key 1.4

Tags: arrays, json, join, merge, jq

I have two files with the following JSON that I need to combine using the relative array position of each object:

PS: - I am restricted to version 1.4 as am on Solaris so don't have the [inputs] feature

File 1

```
{
  "input": [
    {
      "email": "test1@gm.com",
      "firstName": "Fred"
    },
    {
      "email": "someone@gm.com",
      "firstName": "James"
    }
  ]
}
```

File 2:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "id": 50,
      "status": "created"
    },
    {
      "id": 51,
      "status": "rejected"
    }
  ]
}
```

the expected result is the elements of input[1] combined with elements of result[1] and so on as follows:

```
{
  "combined": [
    {
      "email": "test1@gm.com",
      "firstName": "Fred",
      "id": 50,
      "status": "created"
    },
    {
      "email": "someone@gm.com",
      "firstName": "James",
      "id": 51,
      "status": "rejected"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hello, Paolog, do you remember that it is good to mark an answer as accepted if it helped you?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `--slurp` option to read both files into one array, and from there it's relatively simple to loop over the keys of one of the arrays and add the corresponding elements of both arrays together.

```
jq --slurp '
{
  combined: [
    .[0].input as $is|
    .[1].result as $rs|
    range(0; $is|length) as $n|
    $is[$n]+$rs[$n]
  ]
}
' file1.json file2.json
```

Comment: This approach nicely avoids `reduce` but using `keys` introduces an unnecessary inefficiency. It would be far better to use `range(0; $is|length)` to effect the iteration.

Comment: @peak That seems to be right (for values of "far better" equal to about 5% performance gain and about 1% memory saved on 1M entries). Changing the code.

Comment: @MichałPolitowski - By "far better" I had in mind the role that SO plays in illustrating best practices.

Comment: @peak, well, best practices include measuring the impact of a change, don't they? :)

Answer (score 1):

If more recent versions of jq were available to you, you could take advantage of the `transpose` function to combine them rather easily:

```
$ jq -n '{ combined: ([inputs[]] | transpose | map(add)) }' input1.json input2.json
```

However, since you are limited to 1.4, your options are bit limited. When working with multiple files, it's useful to have all the inputs read into memory. `--slurp` allows you to do this reading all inputs in as an array. You will have to zip the inputs together differently however.

```
$ jq --slurp 'add | reduce range(0; .input | length) as $i (.;
    .combined += [.input[$i] + .result[$i]]
) | {combined}' input1.json input2.json
```