# How to combine two arrays by merging each object with jq?

Tags: json, jq

How can I use jq to combine the two files above, into a single array, by merging each object?

I've found [combine array of objects from two files with jq under specific key 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54925675/combine-array-of-objects-from-two-files-with-jq-under-specific-key-1-4) but this is for a specific key.

I've tried:

```
jq -n '{ combined: (transpose | map(add)) }' a.json b.json  
jq: error (at <unknown>): Cannot iterate over null (null)
```

Input:

```
    ==> a.json <==
    [
      {
        "datetime": "2019-12-08 11:34"
      },
      {
        "datetime": "2019-12-08 11:35"
      },
      {
        "datetime": "2019-12-08 12:03"
      }
    ]

    ==> b.json <==
    [
      {
        "command": "cat test.txt"
      },
      {
        "command": "cat test2.txt"
      },
      {
        "command": "cat test3.txt"
      }
    ]
```

Desired output:

```
    [
      {
        "command": "cat test.txt",
        "datetime": "2019-12-08 11:34"
      },
      {
        "command": "cat test2.txt",
        "datetime": "2019-12-08 11:35"
      },
      {
        "command": "cat test3.txt",
        "datetime": "2019-12-08 12:03"
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just slurp them. `-n` is for null input, and is overkill for this trivial task.

```
jq -s 'transpose | map(add)' a.json b.json
```